Calling removeEventListener does not work
I don‘t understand why removeEventListner() is not working in my code.
Below is my code with simplified names etc.:
const form = document.querySelector(".formclass")

function executeUserInput(userInput){
  function sayHello(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("Hello")
  }

  if(userInput === "add"){
    form.addEventListener("submit", sayHello)
  }else{
    form.removeEventListener("submit", sayHello)
  }
}

When I execute this code, and trigger condition1 and else-part multiple times, an eventlistener is added every time I trigger condition1 but the removeEventListener does not remove it. When inspecting in google Dev tools I can also see that the submit listener exists after else-part was executed.
Why?
I did find some questions about this issue on stackoverflow, but none of them helped me
Updated the code to represent my code more precisely, hope this clarifies

Your if statement only runs once, right after the form variable is initialized. If "condition1" is true at that point, the event handler will be added. That if statement (if the code you posted is accurate, which it clearly isn't) will never run again. When posting code in a question, please make sure the code accurately reflects the real situation you are asking about.

Hope my edit clarifies the situation, it in deed was misunderstanding as before, sorry for that

Yes it certainly does!

The .removeEventListener() method makes a direct comparison between the function object you pass to it and all the other registered event handler function objects. If the function you pass is not a registered handler, then it won't do anything.
In this case, you've got a function declared inside that outer function. That means that each time the outer function is called, a new version of the inner event handler is created. If one call to the outer function adds a handler, and the next call should remove the handler, it won't have a reference to the handler function created on the previous call.
Try moving the handler function to outside that outer function (executeUserInput()).
Another thing this will cause is if you call the outer function 3 times in a row, and the condition is always true, you'll get 3 separate event handlers on the form.

Wow, that absolutely makes sense!! Feeling quite bad sitting in front of computer for 2-3 hours and not recognizing.
Already moved function outside and it works fine, thank you very much!!
The last thing you mentioned is actually desired behavior, but thanks for pointing it out as well!
